# Flutter Firebase Setup with FlutterFire

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-tools

I have already setup my app for Android using Manual Setup Method. It is already in production for 2 years. Now I want to release an iOS version.

I just found FlutterFire is a better way for setup but I already have my android app added. I haven't proceeded for adding because I am worried since android app is already there and setting up again might get duplicate package name and affect my production.

Now, How do I switch to FlutterFire for both Android/iOS without affecting the production version of current android app? Or do I have to use the Old way by adding iOS app manually?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't feel comfortable using FlutterFire I would recommend to use the old way, just download the config file from firebase. But in my experience running the FlutterFire doesn't duplicate any package name because it recognizes that it already exists, but of course, this depends on you project settings.